# Loop through attribute of a class and get a count of how many properties that are not null

Tags: c#-4.0

I was wondering if there was a simpler way to do something like this?

```
    public int NonNullPropertiesCount(object entity)
    {
        if (entity == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("A null object was passed in");


        int nonNullPropertiesCount = 0;
        Type entityType = entity.GetType();

        foreach (var property in entityType.GetProperties())
        {
            if (property.GetValue(entity, null) != null)
                nonNullPropertiesCount = nonNullPropertiesCount+ 1;
        }


        return nonNullPropertiesCount;
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
public int NonNullPropertiesCount(object entity)
{
    return entity.GetType()
                 .GetProperties()
                 .Select(x => x.GetValue(entity, null))
                 .Count(v => v != null);
}
```

(Other answers have combined the "fetch the property value" and "test the result for null". Obviously that will work - I just like to separate the two bits out a bit more. It's up to you, of course :)

Comment: Thanks jon, but is it supposed to end with .Select(x => x.GetValue(entity, null) != null).Count() ?

Comment: @zSysop: Nope. That would just project into a sequence of Boolean values, and count *all* of them. This projects into a sequence of property values, and *only* counts those which aren't null.

Comment: It's not compiling here. I'm getting an error that says ") expected"

Comment: @zSysop: Ah yes, I'd missed a closing bracket at the end of the Select call. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is OK, can suggest using Linq

```
entity
  .GetProperties()
  .Count(x=>x.CanRead && x.GetProperty(entity, null) != null)
```

And don't forget to add condition, that property has getter.

Comment: Took a piece of idea from Davita

Answer (score 1):

```
Type entityType = entity.GetType();

int count = entityType.GetProperties().Count(p => p.GetValue(p, null) != null);
```