# How to check with C#, in more elegant way, if only some of the object properties are null?

Tags: c#

I have an objekt:

```
var object = new SomeObjectType()
{
   Prop1 = null,
   Prop2 = null,
   Prop3 = 665
}
```

Assuming that `Prop3` will be never `null`, how can I verify if rest of the properties are `null`, or one of them is not?

Right now I have:

```
if (object.Prop1 == null && object.Prop2 == null)
{
   //do stuff
}
```

But this is very not elegant, especially if I have pore properties to verify. And I have no idea how could I use [Null-conditional operators ?. and ?[]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) in my case.

How to do it with C#?

Comment: Use reflection and try something like `foreach (var property in typeof(SomeObjectType).GetProperties())`

Comment: But then Ill have to skip `Prop3` anyway.

Comment: But if you are checking for `nulls` and one of your properties is never null then does that matter? This was a suggestion to allow for iterating through properties independently of how many there are. If the null count == 1 then all but your fixed property are null; if greater than 1 then ... I think you need to define your requirements a little more.

Comment: Actually this is a great idea, to count how many are nulls or how many are not. I was just thinking about the same right now :) Thank you.

Comment: I've put it in an answer as outline idea.

Comment: So there's a set of properties that must either all be null or all non-null? I'd suggest that maybe they represent something that belongs in another class. Then you'd have a single reference that is either null or non-null. The constructor of the other class can enforce that all properties are non-null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's many ways of doing this, perhaps one of the more easily readable is:

```
var o = new SomeObjectType    // object is a keyword
{
   Prop1 = null,
   Prop2 = null,
   Prop3 = 665
};

if(o is SomeObjectType { Prop1: null, Prop2: null } )
    ; // do stuff
```

Comment: You can definitely use `?.`, `?[]` and `??` as well, but that depends on your actual code. For example, you cannot use `?.` as an l-value, which is something I dearly want.

Answer (score 1):

Putting it in a non-Linq way then try something like this as an outline:

```
int nullCount = 0
foreach (var property in object.GetType().GetProperties()) 
{
    if (property.GetValue(object) == null) nullCount++;
}

if (nullCount == 1)
{
    // do my first thing
}
else
{
    // do my other thing
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look correct - `property` here would be a `PropertyInfo` type, not the value property's value for the given instance. You'd need to also invoke `GetValue` and pass the instance for consideration as the argument. At that point you can check if the result for null.

Comment: How about this idea? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328411/loop-through-attribute-of-a-class-and-get-a-count-of-how-many-properties-that-ar/4328437#4328437

Comment: @bakunet Neat - Iike it

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with,

```
public bool hasMethod(object yourObject, string Prop)
{
    return yourObject.GetType().GetMethod(Prop) != null;
}
```